# How to I center a JButton on one dimension?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I want to have a button with centered horizontal alignment (x) but be able to move it down a bit on the vertical (y) axis. Is this possible and how do I do it?

Comment: One way would be to set an empty border for the JPanel with more space at the top than the bottom.

Comment: See: [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm honestly not sure what I did (this is my first time writing a GUI program) but It is now centered using setVerticalAlignment(JButton.CENTER) and then setting the x to 0 while setting Borders. I accidentally fixed it (before it wouldn't change anything) but now it works, thank you for the help though!

Comment: *I'm honestly not sure what I did* - then you really haven't learned anything, which will only cause problems going forward. Using the proper layout manager and border will solve you problem in a single statement or two. Post a proper [mre] if you want a real answer.

Comment: Okay understood. I'm sorry for all the confusion and unclarity; this is my first time asking for help here. I'm very sorry for wasting your time again, thank you for your help and time!